# F# Compilation error when implementing C# interface

Tags: interface, f#

I have this interface written in C#...

```
public interface IFoo {
    IEnumerable<T> Bar<T>(IEnumerable<T> list); 
}
```

A simple C# implementation is straightforward...

```
public class CsFoo : IFoo
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Bar<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

A simple F# implementation is also straightforward...

```
type FsFoo() =
    interface IFoo with
        member this.Bar list =
            list
```

But when I try to *match* on *list*...

```
type FsFoo() =
    interface IFoo with
        member this.Bar list =
            match list with
                | [] -> []        // error                      
                | list -> list
```

I get this error...

> This expression was expected to have type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'a> but here has type 'b list

Can you help me understand this error and how I should change the F# code to fix it?

Thank you...

Comment: You're trying to use list pattern matching with the sequence.
Actually, the error states it rather clearly.
If you want to use list pattern matching, you have to convert the sequence to the list: `list |> Seq.toList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface does not use a list, it uses `IEnumerable<T>` and because of that you should use `Seq` when dealing with the interface in F#.

```
type FsFoo() =
    interface IFoo with
        member this.Bar list =
            match Seq.isEmpty list with
                | true -> Seq.empty        // input is empty               
                | false -> list            // input is not empty
```

But it's actually pointless, because it just passes parameter value as result value, so it's exactly the same as

```
type FsFoo() =
    interface IFoo with
        member this.Bar list = list
```

Comment: Okay.  That makes sense.  (But perhaps I erred here by contriving an example that results in an error message that is a duplicate of the one I see in my actual program, but does not represent my actual problem.)